# Running time of the function below

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

The outer loop runs n times but i am unable to find the running time of inner loop and the total running time, can you please help regarding this?

```
def function(n)
    count=0
    if n<=0:
        return
    for i in range(1,n):
        j=1
        While j<n:
            j=j+i
            count = count+1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop runs `O(n/i)` times, for each value of `i`.

If we sum it over all values of `i` we get:

```
n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n = n* (1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n)
```

The sum `1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n` is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which is in `O(logn)`, so your code is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: The explanation is wrong. If you take a look at my answer, it will show you the inner loop doesn't run `n/i` times. `10/7 ~= 1.4`, `10/8 = 1.25` and it runs 2 times in both cases. Just an example.

Comment: @LuisÁvila It runs `floor(n/i)` times, in asymptotic terms - the difference between `n/i` and `floor(n/i)` is insignificant.

Comment: Not true again. `10/1` runs 9 times. `floor(10)` won't return 9. I've tried to go that route as well, but it was wrong.

Comment: Also, `10/4` would `floor` 2 and it runs 3 times. Anyway, you're right ;)

Comment: @LuisÁvila Are you going to nit-pick it to death? It's `O(n/i)`, the exact constants are insignificant for big O here. If you want the exact number it's  `1 + floor((n-2)/i))`, or something very close to it.